# LazyReference with double-checked locking and null handling

Tags: java, null, volatile, lazy-initialization, double-checked-locking

I've been using `LazyReference` class for a few years (not on a regular basis of course, but sometimes it is very useful). The class can be seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/warp-persist/source/browse/trunk/warp-persist/src/com/wideplay/warp/persist/internal/LazyReference.java). Credits go to Robbie Vanbrabant (class author) and Joshua Bloch with his famous "Effective Java 2nd edt." (original code).

The class works correctly (in Java 5+) but there is one little potential issue. If `instanceProvider` returns `null` (well it must not according to Guice `Provider.get()` contract, but…) then on every execution of `LazyReference.get()` method the LOCK will be held and `instanceProvider.get` will be called over and over again. It looks like a good punishment for those who break the contracts (he-he), but what if one really needs to lazily initialize a field with the possibility to set the `null` value?

I modified LazyReference a little bit:

```
public class LazyReference<T> {

  private final Object LOCK = new Object();

  private volatile T instance;

  private volatile boolean isNull;

  private final Provider<T> instanceProvider;

  private LazyReference(Provider<T> instanceProvider) {
    this.instanceProvider = instanceProvider;
  }

  public T get() {
    T result = instance;
    if (result == null && !isNull) {
      synchronized (LOCK) {
        result = instance;
        if (result == null && !isNull) {
          instance = result = instanceProvider.get();
          isNull = (result == null);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

IMHO it should work just fine (if you have another opinion please post your comments and criticisms). But I wonder what will happen if I remove the `volatile` modifier from `isNull` boolean (leaving it for `instance` of course)? Will it still work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Neil Coffey, this code contains a race condition, but it can be easily fixed as follows (note that `instance` don't need to be `volatile`):

```
public class LazyReference<T> {     
  private T instance;
  private volatile boolean initialized;
  ...
  public T get() {
    if (!initialized) {
      synchronized (LOCK) {
        if (!initialized) {
          instance = instanceProvider.get();
          initialized = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: `instance don't need to be volatile` - 
Good point! Since `instance` is written before volatile field `initialized` it will be visible to all other threads that read `initialized`.

Answer (score 3):

The above code has a race condition: instance may be set to the "real" null from the result of instanceProvider.get() before isNull has been set.

Are you sure it wouldn't be easier for you to just scrap this complicated nonsense and synchronise properly. I bet you will not be able to measure any difference in performance and it will be easier to verify that your code is correct.

Comment: Yes you are right: `instance` may be set to "real" `null` before `isNull` is set to `true`. But in this case execution will go through synchronized block, in which `isNull` value will be already equal to 'true'. Then second conditional check will evaluate to `false` and `instanceProvider.get` won't be called more than one time. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Answering your question: yes, it would be easier to use plain synchronization or use original `LazyReference` (which works flawlessly if one respects Provider contract). The purpose of question is a personal theoretical interest. **axtavt** has already posted more simple and elegant solution than mine - well, will practise more.